# multicast loopback in c

Tags: c, linux, multicast

I am trying to test multicast loopback which the clients would join the group
and the server will multicast messgaes to those client in this group constrained
in 127.0.0.1  only !!!!!

refering to : http://www.tenouk.com/Module41c.html   , the source are :

The Server :

```
struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
int sd;
char databuf[1024] = "Multicast test message lol!";
int datalen = sizeof(databuf);

int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to send. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n");

    /* Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a */
    /* group address of 225.1.1.1 and port 5555. */
    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.0");
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(4321);

    /* Disable loopback so you do not receive your own datagrams.
     * {
     * char loopch = 0;
     * if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char *)&loopch, sizeof(loopch)) < 0)
     * {
     * perror("Setting IP_MULTICAST_LOOP error");
     * close(sd);
     * exit(1);
     * }
     * else
     * printf("Disabling the loopback...OK.\n");
     * }
     * */

    /* Set local interface for outbound multicast datagrams. */
    /* The IP address specified must be associated with a local, */
    /* multicast capable interface. */
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Setting local interface error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Setting the local interface...OK\n");

    /* Send a message to the multicast group specified by the*/
    /* groupSock sockaddr structure. */
    /*int datalen = 1024;*/
    while( 1 ){
        usleep( 1000 ) ;
        if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Sending datagram message error");
        }
        else
            printf("Sending datagram message...OK\n");
    } 
    /* Try the re-read from the socket if the loopback is not disable
     * if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)
     * {
     * perror("Reading datagram message error\n");
     * close(sd);
     * exit(1);
     * }
     * else
     * {
     * printf("Reading datagram message from client...OK\n");
     * printf("The message is: %s\n", databuf);
     * }
     * */
    return 0;
}
```

and the client source :

```
struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[1024];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("Opening datagram socket error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Opening datagram socket....OK.\n");

    /* Enable SO_REUSEADDR to allow multiple instances of this */
    /* application to receive copies of the multicast datagrams. */
    {
        int reuse = 1;
        if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
        {
            perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
            printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");
    }

    /* Bind to the proper port number with the IP address */
    /* specified as INADDR_ANY. */
    memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));
    localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localSock.sin_port = htons(4321);
    localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))
    {
        perror("Binding datagram socket error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Binding datagram socket...OK.\n");

    /* Join the multicast group 226.1.1.1 on the local 203.106.93.94 */
    /* interface. Note that this IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option must be */
    /* called for each local interface over which the multicast */
    /* datagrams are to be received. */
    group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.0");
    group.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Adding multicast group error");
        close(sd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");

    /* Read from the socket. */
    datalen = sizeof(databuf);
    while( 1 ){
        if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) <= 0)
        {
            perror("Reading datagram message error");
            close(sd);
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Reading datagram message...OK.\n");
            printf("The message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);
        }
    } //while 
    return 0;
}
```

after add the following as root , it works fine :

```
route add -net 224.0.0.0 netmask 240.0.0.0 dev lo
ifconfig lo multicast
```

If I have one client.exe running , everything is perfect , however ,
if I run 2 copies of  client.exe  , then server.exe or client.exe is easily to hang ,
If I need more than one application to join the group(in this sample 224.0.0.0)
, what should I modify the source so that many clients may join muticast gruop
and receive packets without troubles ?!

Comment: In client, could you try to `recvfrom` instead of `read` with `"224.0.0.0"` as as source?

Comment: @purplepsycho , struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;  socklen_t  peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_storage);   recvfrom(sd, databuf, datalen,0,(struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_len) still encounter the same problem ,  one of those client.exe  will hang after run several minutes .

Comment: Especially while run ,for example , 4 copies of client.exe , then you run 5'th  client.exe  ,  one of the 4 client.exe will  die easily .